# Creating multiple series in chart

Tags: javascript, php, sql, highcharts

I don't know how to create multiple series with data.I manage to do with only on ID from table. But when I have to take all data for every ID , didnt work.
This is php code

```
<?php include 'login/dbconf.php';
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
$conn->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$external_cow_id = $_POST['external_cow_id'];
$query = "SELECT testing_date, delta_mp  FROM  cow_result WHERE id='{$id}'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if ( ! $result ) {
    echo mysqli_error();
    die;
}

$testing_date = array();
$delta_mp = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($result); $x++) {
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $testing_date[]=$data['testing_date'];
    $delta_mp[]=$data['delta_mp'];
}

//echo json_encode($data);     

mysqli_close($server);
?>
```

And this is js I use for one cow only.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    backgroundColor: null
},

title: {
    text: 'FPA RESULTS',
    style: {
        color: '#000'
    }
},
xAxis: {
    categories: <?php echo json_encode($testing_date); ?>
},

yAxis: { 
    labels: {
        style: {
            color: '#CCC'
        },

    },

    gridLineColor: '#333'

},

series: [{
    name:[<?php echo json_encode($external_cow_id); ?>] ,
    data: [<?php echo join($delta_mp, ',') ?>],
    color: 'blue',
    shadow: {
        color: 'blue',
        width: 10,
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0
    } 
}]
});
```

And I need something like this
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFF7T.png)

Every cow has multiple testing_date and delta_mp...
Thanks for help

Comment: You need to query 3 times (depending on what you want), then add each of the results to `series` array.

Comment: Chart for one cow looks like this http://prntscr.com/hmxnaa and I need all cow from one farm in chart... And dont know how to do it..

Comment: If `id` in the table is the cow, just include it in your resultset (id, testing_date, delta_mp) and widen the query result like `WHERE id='1' or id='2' or id='3'`, then in your for loop create individual arrays for each of the cows, then plop it in the javascript in series, or populate series in php and just pass that.

Comment: Or make a function which fetches the result for each cow, and loop over the ids.

Comment: So I manage to get for each cow json with all data I need. But not sure what to do next and how to put each cow in series.

Comment: Output I get is this
[{"id":"111","testing_date":"2017-12-04","delta_mp":"123"},{"id":"111","testing_date":"2017-11-27","delta_mp":"343"},{"id":"111","testing_date":"2017-11-27","delta_mp":"456"}]

[{"id":"222","testing_date":"2017-11-26","delta_mp":"121"},{"id":"222","testing_date":"2017-11-07","delta_mp":"2324"}]

Comment: This demo shows how you can prepare your data before passing it to Highcharts constructor: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/7w8czLrq/